# Estimated value of a sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

> Let there be three cash registers within a small market. Each of these registers serves an average of k customers per hour, independently of the other registers. If all three cash registers work for an hour, estimate the total number of customers served.

My solution:

Let $X_n$ denote the number of customers served at the $n$-th cash register within an hour. Then $X_n \sim P(k)$, where $P(k)$ is the Poisson distribution with a parameter $k$. The total number of customers served within one hour would then be a random variable $X$, such that $X=\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i$ and therefore $X \sim P(\sum _{i=1}^3 k)$, i.e. $X \sim P(3k)$. So, we're looking for $P\{X=1\}$, which is $3*k*e^{-3k}$.

I want to ask if my solution is correct, since my textbook doesn't have an answer sheet.

Comment: An estimate of the total number of customers served would be $E(X)$, not $P(X=1)$. You have the correct distribution for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is somewhat idiosyncratically phrased – one usually considers the *expected value* of a random variable, rather than *estimating* its value. As Mick A pointed out, the expected value could serve as an estimate of the value, whereas the probability of the variable taking the value $1$ is not a useful estimate of its value.

You determined the correct distribution for $X$, but note that this was a) only possible because the individual distributions had the propitious property of adding up nicely, and b) not necessary, since by the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) you could have just added up the expected values of the individual distributions.